# How to redirect from one webapp to another with token in headers without server side inolvement?

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, fetch, window

I want to redirect from one webapp to another webapp ( on different domains) and need to pass token in headers ( any other suggestion for passing sensitive information without server side involvement will also be of great help).

Things I tried:-

1. Adding all data in URL params, redirecting to URL, storing them in session storage and then `window.location.href = window.location.orgin`.

(**Problem**: my token is visible in params till the time redirection happens ( also this method is to be avoided as per the requirement)

2. Passing token in cookies with window.open(url,"_blank")

   `window.document.cookie = "token=loremipsum12345u89`

(**Problem**: not able to set https cookies and in encrypted manner)

Any direction for the same problem would be helpful.

Comment: If both the webapps can be available on same host. e.g. test.com/webapp1 and test.com/webapp2. You can make use of local storage to access the data in both the apps.

Comment: Both are on different domains